# Improving the runtime of cosine similarity on a large dataset of phrases

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark, data-science, cosine-similarity

I am using cosine similarity to group similar phrases together, in order to reduce the number of phrase entries I am storing in my DB.

The grouping process depends on generating pairings of similar phrases. I am following Python implementation of cosine similarity in the following article to do this: https://towardsdatascience.com/surprisingly-effective-way-to-name-matching-in-python-1a67328e670e.

A key part of the implementation is the `sparse_dot_topn` library (but it is also slowest part). In 10k articles and the 3.5 million phrases within them, cosine similarity takes 70 minutes. I am planning to run this on 1 million articles but with this runtime it won't be feasable, especially because the runtime does not grow linearly with more phrases inputted.

My first approach to reducing runtime is to use the threaded version of the `sparse_dot_topn` function (it is written using Cython). Although it does reduce runtime, the above benchmark scores are from this approach.

My next approach is to process these phrases in batches. So for example, I run the grouping process on every x number of documents. This also reduces runtime but the issue is phrases within each batch are not compared to phrases within other batches. I have tried to carry some phrases over to successive batches, but the more I carry over the longer the runtime for the individual batch.

I have looked into PySpark but I am not sure how I would integrate it, especially with the built-in `sparse_dot_topn` function. Here is what my function for creating matches looks like:

```py
# calculate the similarity between two vectors of TF-IDF values the Cosine Similarity is usually used.
# result matrix in a very sparse terms and Scikit-learn deals with this nicely by returning a sparse CSR matrix.
def awesome_cossim_top(A, B, ntop, lower_bound=0):
    # force A and B as a CSR matrix.
    # If they have already been CSR, there is no overhead
    A = A.tocsr()
    B = B.tocsr()
    M, _ = A.shape
    _, N = B.shape
 
    idx_dtype = np.int32
 
    nnz_max = M*ntop
 
    indptr = np.zeros(M+1, dtype=idx_dtype)
    indices = np.zeros(nnz_max, dtype=idx_dtype)
    data = np.zeros(nnz_max, dtype=A.dtype)
    n_jobs = 8

    ct.sparse_dot_topn_threaded(
        M, N, np.asarray(A.indptr, dtype=idx_dtype),
        np.asarray(A.indices, dtype=idx_dtype),
        A.data,
        np.asarray(B.indptr, dtype=idx_dtype),
        np.asarray(B.indices, dtype=idx_dtype),
        B.data,
        ntop,
        lower_bound,
        indptr, indices, data, n_jobs)

    return csr_matrix((data,indices,indptr),shape=(M,N))
```

Comment: `ct` and `csr_matrix` are not defind, so the code will not work.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example